# Exclamation Mark on Input Angular Material

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular-material

Is it possible show an Exclamation mark when input is invalid?

Like this

[image]

I didn't find this on Angular Material documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matsuffix, [Prefix & Suffix in Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix-amp-suffix)

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-hint>name</mat-hint>
    <mat-icon matSuffix><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;" aria-hidden="true"></i></mat-icon>
// add logic when to display the exclamation circle
    <input matInput placeholder="enter name" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

I used a fontawesome icon, but you can add your icon or css styled exclamation mark.
Obviously, you need to add logic for when to display the error.
Good Luck!

Comment: @AlexandreBueno if this is the answer please mark it as such. Happy to help!